# storing hashmap in specific memory in java

Tags: java, hashmap, heap-memory

Is there any way to store HashMap in a specific memory location or within specific memory area (lets say memory address from 0 to 100).

As per my understanding it is possible by modifying the hashCode() function. Can anyone share the code for the same ?

Comment: If by memory you mean heap, the answer is simply no

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

`hashCode()` 's purpose is simply to be a unique id for *distinct* java objects in the VM where the code is running. It does **not** affect the object's position inside the *virtual* memory used by the VM. **It works the other way**, at least in `Object` 's implementation of the method, `hashCode()` gets you an integer describing the object's address in this virtual memory.

If you are to change it, you should follow these guidelines. I think [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) explanation from the Java docs can make things clear:

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>     execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>     consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>     of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the
>     equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the
>     two objects must produce the same integer result. 
>     .
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the
>     equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>     each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>     However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>     integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>     hash tables.
>
> the hashCode method defined by class Object **does return distinct integers for distinct objects**.

Here comes the implementation part:

> (This is typically implemented by **converting the internal address of the object into an integer**, but this implementation technique is **not required** by the JavaTM programming language.)

EDIT:

In the case of HashMap the `hashCode()` method is inherited from `AbstractMap` and works as described in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#hashCode()):

> Returns the hash code value for this map. The hash code of a map is
>   defined to be the **sum of the hash codes of each entry** in the map's
>   entrySet() view. This ensures that m1.equals(m2) implies that
>   m1.hashCode()==m2.hashCode() for any two maps m1 and m2, **as required
>   by the general contract of Object.hashCode()**.

As you can see it follows the contract specified above

Hope this helps

Comment: @Aniket did you understand the explanation?